# Remoção de dados com TRUNCATE não seria comando DDL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lendo o livro OCA Oracle Database SQL Exam Guide(`1Z0-071`) me deparei com a seguinte definição para o `TRUNCATE` no tópico de *DDL*(*Data Definition Language*):

> Removes all the rows—in other words, data—from an existing table in
>   the database. TRUNCATE is something of a brute-force alternative to
>   the DELETE statement, in that TRUNCATE gives up recovery options
>   offered by DELETE in exchange for faster performance. These
>   differences in approach are the reason TRUNCATE is categorized as DDL
>   while DELETE is DML.

[Tradução](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=pt&text=Removes%20all%20the%20rows%E2%80%94in%20other%20words%2C%20data%E2%80%94from%20an%20existing%20table%20in%0A%20the%20database.%20TRUNCATE%20is%20something%20of%20a%20brute-force%20alternative%20to%0A%20the%20DELETE%20statement%2C%20in%20that%20TRUNCATE%20gives%20up%20recovery%20options%0A%20offered%20by%20DELETE%20in%20exchange%20for%20faster%20performance.%20These%0A%20differences%20in%20approach%20are%20the%20reason%20TRUNCATE%20is%20categorized%20as%20DDL%0A%20while%20DELETE%20is%20DML.) via Google Translator:

> Remove todas as linhas - em outras palavras, dados - de um tabela
>   existente no banco de dados. TRUNCATE é uma espécie de força bruta
>   alternativa à declaração DELETE, em que TRUNCATE desiste opções de
>   recuperação oferecidas pelo DELETE em troca de mais rápido desempenho.
>   Estas diferenças de abordagem são a razão TRUNCATE é categorizado como
>   DDL, enquanto DELETE é DML.

---

Ao ler isso, fiquei mais atento quando o assunto envolvesse *DDL* e algo relacionado à remoção de dados, uma vez que o `TRUNCATE` está ligado à isso.

No final do capítulo, na sessão de questões, encontrei a seguinte questão:

```
Describe the Purpose of DDL
10- What is one of the purposes of DDL? (Choose the best answer.)
A. Query data from a given table
B. Issue privileges to users
C. Remove existing data from a database table
D. None of the above
```

Minha resposta foi a alternativa `B`(por ter de escolher a melhor resposta), porém, pra mim a alternativa `C` também estava correta(levando em consideração o primeiro trecho destacado na pergunta) e, ao visualizar as respostas, estavam as seguintes explicações:

> **B.** The GRANT statement is part of DDL and is used to issue privileges
>   to a user.
>  **A**, **C**, and **D** are incorrect. Querying data is performed using
>   the DML statement SELECT. Use the DML statements UPDATE or DELETE to
>   remove data from a database table. UPDATE can be used to remove data
>   from one or more columns in a given row, and DELETE can be used to
>   remove an entire row. “None of the above” does not apply since option
>   B is correct.

[Tradução](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=pt&text=B.%20The%20GRANT%20statement%20is%20part%20of%20DDL%20and%20is%20used%20to%20issue%20privileges%20to%20a%20user.%0AA%2C%20C%2C%20and%20D%20are%20incorrect.%20Querying%20data%20is%20performed%20using%20the%20DML%20statement%20SELECT.%20Use%20the%20DML%20statements%20UPDATE%20or%20DELETE%20to%20remove%20data%20from%20a%20database%20table.%20UPDATE%20can%20be%20used%20to%20remove%20data%20from%20one%20or%20more%20columns%20in%20a%20given%20row%2C%20and%20DELETE%20can%20be%20used%20to%20remove%20an%20entire%20row.%20%E2%80%9CNone%20of%20the%20above%E2%80%9D%20does%20not%20apply%20since%20option%20B%20is%20correct.) via Google Translator:

> **B.** A instrução GRANT faz parte da DDL e é usada para emitir
>   privilégios para um usuário. 
>  **A**, **C** e **D** estão incorretos. A consulta de
>   dados é realizada usando a instrução DML SELECT. Use as instruções DML
>   UPDATE ou DELETE para remover dados de uma tabela de banco de dados.
>   UPDATE pode ser usado para remover dados de uma ou mais colunas em uma
>   determinada linha, e DELETE pode ser usado para remover uma linha
>   inteira. “Nenhuma das opções acima” não se aplica, pois a opção B está
>   correta.

- A alternativa `C` realmente está incorreta?
- Seria um equívoco do autor afirmar que a alternativa `C` está
  incorreta?
- Se a questão fosse multiplas escolhas, eu poderia considerá-la correta?

Comment: `GRANT` e `REVOKE` tem mais a ver com DCL (_data control language_) do que com DDL. Pelo menos no mundo tradicional e abstrato do SQL fora de uma _engine_ específica. Mas tem gente que fala que `SELECT` não é DML, mas DQL... cada um inventa os termos que quiser e usa como quiser...

Comment: esse livro é o oficial né? estou vendo com uns amigos sobre a opinião deles... para mim a resposta não seria B.... como o Jefferson falou, é DCL... Com a definição de truncate, minha interpretação é que a resposta correta seria C.

Answer (score 1):

Conversei com um amigo que está estudando para certificação, ele falou que em alguns casos realmente só existe o conceito DDL e DML. Eliminando a ideia inicial de que a resposta B seria para DCL.

Acho que a C não foi considerada para a resposta, por ser um conceito 'simples' de delete. Seria referente a Trucante e em consequência a DDL se fosse uma descrição mais específica do seu funcionamento. Mas por estar de uma forma que possibilita um entendimento dúbio, poderia ser uma questão anulada... que ocorre muito em questão desta natureza.

Comment: Como nesse caso, porém, foi dito acima, pelo autor que o `TRUNCATE` é uma insturção DDL. A principal dúvida era saber se mesmo nessas provas de nível global seria possível a sua anulação.